# Finding bases for subspaces of $F^5$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Find bases for the following subspaces of $F^5$:

$W_1 = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5) \in F^5 : a_1-a_3-a_4=0\}$
$W_2=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5) \in F^5 : a_2=a_3=a_4, a_1+a_5=0\}$

What are the dimensions of $W_1, W_2$?

**My attempt:**

For the first case:

$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
a_3 \\
a_4 \\
a_5 \end{array} \right)
= a_3 \left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \end{array} \right)
+  a_4 \left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \end{array} \right)
+ a_2 \left( \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \end{array} \right)
+ a_5 \left( \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \end{array} \right)$$

And so these four column vectors form the basis and the dimension is 4.

For the second case:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{c}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
a_3 \\
a_4 \\
a_5 \end{array} \right)
= a_1 \left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
-1 \end{array} \right)
+ a_2 \left( \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
0 \end{array} \right)$$

And these column vectors form a basis and the dimension is 2.

**Question:**

1. Is my approach correct?
2. Is it ok to write these vectors as column vectors like I have? So should I put them in the standard $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)$ form?

Comment: I couldn't fix the MathJax here, sorry! The $\cdot$ should be +

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you; if you right click the math and select `Show Math As > TeX Commands`, you'll be able to see how I formatted any given line.  To view the entirety of the raw input for the question, click `edit` below the question.

Comment: Also, I recommend the `\pmatrix` command for future linear-algebraic LaTeX endeavors, as in `\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4\\5&6}`, which renders as
$$
\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4\\5&6}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're solution looks correct, at least in spirit.

It is okay to write the vectors as you have, but in this context it's probably clearer if you have them in row-vector form.  Personally, I think row-vectors are easier to write out anyway and write column vectors as $(a_1,\dots,a_n)^T$.

While the basis you provide for each space is indeed a correct basis, it's not clear what your "approach" was in this problem.  How do you know that your basis for the subspaces are, in fact, bases?  How do you know that your vectors lie in the subspace?  How do you know they span the subspace?  How do you know that they are linearly independent?

Finally, a technical point: you wrote the expanded form of a vector in your space, but you technically did not write what your basis was.

In particular, your first basis is
$$
\{
(1,0,1,0,0),(1,0,0,1,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,1)
\}
$$
And your second is
$$
\{
(1,0,0,0,-1),(0,1,1,1,0)
\}
$$

Comment: Thank you. I was confused whether I needed to show the linear independence part. The spanning part is apparent here though, right?

Comment: @Diya to be fair, I can't be sure you do need to show linear independence at all; it says to "find a basis", which may or may not (depending on the taste of the teacher) entail proving that your set is indeed a basis.  My guess is that what you've written here is enough, lack of "proof" notwithstanding.

Comment: Here is a question to consider though: how do you know that there isn't some vector missing from either of your bases that you just happened to miss?  It's one thing to say that your answer "looks right", but how do you *know* that it is?

Comment: I need to see that the number of vectors matches the dimension?

Comment: But how do you know the dimension?

Comment: I know it's less than 5, but I don't know the exact dimension. Is there another way to check then?

Comment: So the "less than 5" trick works well for the first question, but not the second.  If you'd like a nice way to rigorously justify the dimensions of these sorts of spaces, I'd look into the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).  Ostensibly, this says that the dimension of the space will be the dimension of the space minus the number of "="s necessary to define it. Note that this is necessarily at least the dimension of the space minus the number of "="s that are actually used.

Comment: If none of this looks familiar, don't worry about it.  You probably won't need to prove this kind of thing until you've become comfortable with the vocabulary used in that link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17014/discussion-between-diya-and-omnomnomnom).